# Change FTPClient port in order to send a command

Tags: java, server, port, ftp-client

I'm connecting and logging in to a server on port 21. What I want to do next is to send a command string, however I have been instructed to send this command through port 50.

How do I change the port to 50 whilst connected on port 21?

I have tried connecting to the server on port 50 intially, and the onnection is refused. I have tried sending the command whilst connected on port 21 using `ftpClient.sendCommand` and I get a reply code `500 Unknown command`

Comment: What command are you sending, what FTP server are you connecting to and what is the ftp client you're using?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give out that information. I'm using apache commons FTP client

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you connect, the server controls the port assignment.  So when you issue a pasv command (passive mode), it typically sends you back an IP / Port to connect to for the data connection.  I'm not aware of anything that will allow you to do what you want.  The server can restrict the port range for these types of things.  Here's a nice explanation that goes over this.

[Active vs Passive FTP](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/Active-v-s-Passive-FTP-Simplified)

You may be able to send a PORT command to connect to port 50 specifically, but it's really unusual to do something like this.

** Edit **

There's two things you can try, I've never used either, so YMMV.

In Active mode, the client gives the server a port to connect to.

Try setting the default port to 50 and turn on Active mode.  Hopefully this is on your internal networks, because this would never get past security for a firewall request.

```
client.setDefaultPort(50);
client.enterLocalActiveMode(); // Apache FTPClient
```

For Passive mode, you can try to set the active port range.

```
client.setActivePortRange(50, 50)
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

You should ask what mode the server is expecting.

Comment: Thanks I use `enterLocalPassiveMode()` before sending the command. I still seem to get 500 unknown when I use `ftpClient.getReplyString()`

Comment: @steam1234322 Updated the answer

Comment: @steam1234322 You may also be able to open the connection and send the commands manually to the client.  sendCommand(FTPCmd.PORT, "50"); but at that point, your going to probably need to do some coding to manage the connection.

Answer (score -1):

You should go back to the one who told you this requirement and ask about specifics because - to be blunt - the whole thing doesn't make real sense:

- FTP works with two connections, control and data. The control channel is the one you open on port 21 and there is only this one, you can't change it back to another port afterwards. So "send a command on port 50 but connect on port 21" is not a thing with FTP.
- A data connection on a port < 1024 is not usual, so it's hard to believe that the one with that requirement meant that, either. For one that would require active FTP connections that everybody nowadays tries to avoid because they are a pain to configure. Opening a listener on a port < 1024 would require root-privileges on Unix-systems which is unlikely you will get just for doing FTP-transfers.

You also said that the command you actually try to send to the server is confidential. I find that hard to believe but if it really is that would mean that we're talking about a non-standard FTP-server working with its own set of FTP-commands, i.e. regular FTP-clients might not be able to do what you need at all.

So go back to the one who gave you this requirement and ask, what the heck he's talking about, ideally with an example how to do it, let's say using the FTP-client that comes with the Windows Command-Shell.